# byte[] to string conversion

Tags: java, php, gearman

Hiii,

I am using Gearman to handle communication between PHP and java. I am trying to send array from PHP using json_encode to java worker.
At php Side:

```
public function test()
{
    $test = $this->serviceManager->get('test\Model\test');
    //print_r($test);exit;
    $message = array(
        'to'        =>  'abhi',
        'message'   =>  'this is a test',
    );
    $test->sendtoJavaWorker(json_encode($message));
}
```

At java side:

```
@Override
public byte[] work(String function, byte[] data, GearmanFunctionCallback callback) throws Exception {

    String json = new String(data, "UTF-8");

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(json)); 

    String to = (String) jsonObject.get("to");

    return data;
}
```

Now I am getting json value as shown in picture like ""{\"to\":\"abhi\",\"message\":\"this is a test\"}"". Can someone help.

[image]

For time being, I m fixing this by using this code

```
String json = new String(data);
    json = json.toString().replace("\\", "");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(json);
    sb.deleteCharAt(0);
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);
    json = sb.toString();

    System.out.println(json);
```

And then I am getting answer like:

[image]

Comment: And what is wrong with that data?

Comment: See the highlight text in the debugger... I have updated the text.

Comment: Why you use `String.valueOf(json)` ? json is already a string! How looks like the `jsonObject`?

Comment: Okay, I removed it still the answer is coming the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiii,
     I got the answer, I was sending array after using json_encode to gearman, turns out sending directly to it worked.

```
public function test()
{
    $test = $this->serviceManager->get('test\Model\test');
    //print_r($test);exit;
    $message = array(
        'to'        =>  'abhi',
        'message'   =>  'this is a test',
    );
    $test->sendtoJavaWorker($message);
}
```